# Is it possible to integrate Waterline with StrongLoop/Loopback?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, strongloop

I have a fair amount of Waterline specific code (static functions built into Sails models) that I'd like to reuse in a Strongloop/Loopback app. How can I do that?